# Google sheets: possible to increment row references rather than column references using fill-down?

Tags: google-sheets

When using fill down on a column is it possible to increment row references rather than column references:

```
| --------------------- |  
| =dogs!B15+cats!B27    |  
| --------------------- |  
| =dogs!C15+cats!C27    |  
| --------------------- |  
| =dogs!D15+cats!D27    |  
| --------------------- |
```

rather than:

```
| --------------------- |  
| =dogs!B15+cats!B27    |  
| --------------------- |  
| =dogs!B16+cats!B28    |  
| --------------------- |  
| =dogs!B17+cats!B29    |  
| --------------------- |
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of filling down, use an array formula with `transpose()`, like this:

`=arrayformula(transpose(dogs!B15:D15 + cats!B27:D27)))`